# C++: Funny string comparison crash

Tags: c++, strcmp, strncmp

I'm trying to take in a simple command line argument in a C++ program to trigger different program behavior - when you include a "y" (or any string starting with y - I don't really care) the program displays some intermeadiate results.
When I run with

> ccal pix.txt

everything works fine.

When I use

> ccal pix.txt yes

It runs OK, shows my pix and crashes at the very end.

Also,

> ccal pix.txt no

runs everything OK without showing pix (like it should), and still crashes at the very end.

Here's the relevant code - what am I doing wrong?

```
void dumpFloatMatrix(Mat m){
for(int i = 0; i < m.cols; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < m.rows; j++){
        char *buff = new char[10];
        sprintf(buff, "%5.1f ", m.at<float>(i,j));
        cout << buff;
        delete buff;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
 }
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
char* outFile;
bool showPix = false;

// Take in command line args
switch(argc){
case 3:
    if(strncmp(argv[2], "y", 1) == 0)
        showPix = true;
    outFile = argv[1];
    break;
case 2:
    outFile = argv[1];
    break;
default:
    cout << "Usage: ccal INPUT_LIST_FILE" << endl;
    return -1;
}
Mat cameraMatrix(3, 3, CV_32FC1);
dumpFloatMatrix(cameraMatrix);
return 0;
}
```

The weird thing is that even when I switch the test in case 3 to something like this:

```
        if(argv[2][0] == 'y')
```

I still get the same behavior.  I can't for the life of me figure out why.

Comment: The problem is probably elsewhere in your code; please construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: So far, nothing that looks buggy. We probably need more code.

Comment: You could use a debugger to find out where the crash really is.

Comment: At the very end of *what*. There is nothing after the switch, and no write operations presented that could cause corruption. You wanna show the code that *uses* these data values?? The lack of a closing brace for `main()` suggests your problem is *after* this.

Comment: fatman, follow the direction @WhozCraig is pointing you in.  I.e., we need to see the code that comes after the switch.

Comment: @Griwes:  I'd love to not deal with char* - how do I bring in a command line argument with a string?

Comment: The actual arguments to the `main` function can't be changed, however all strings you fetch from the `argv` array (like `outFile` in this case) could be `std::string` instances.

Comment: is that really everything? i can't see how you use the `outFile` and `showPix` variables

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> args; for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) args.emplace_back(argv[i]);`

Comment: @DWright:  this is the minimal test-case that reproduces the error, per Oli Charlesworth 's comment. The rest is a whole lot of almost certainly irrelevant OpenCV code.

Comment: @ Griwes - i don't have C11 support, can I use push_back() instead?

Comment: Also, this:

 `case 3:{
  string answer = argv[2];
  if(answer == "y")
   showPix = true;
  outFile = argv[1];
  break;
 }`

doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but this is pure lunacy:

```
for(int j = 0; j < m.rows; j++){
    char *buff = new char[10];
    sprintf(buff, "%5.1f ", m.at<float>(i,j));
    cout << buff;
    delete buff;
}
```

Calling new/delete for a 10 byte array will cost 16-32 bytes of memory plus the ten bytes you wanted [probably rounded to 16, 32 or 64 bytes]. And the call to new and delete respectively. Yes, I'm sure `cout << buff` will take a lot more cycles, but those are in some way necessary.

Either use:

```
for(int j = 0; j < m.rows; j++){
    char buff[10];
    sprintf(buff, "%5.1f ", m.at<float>(i,j));
    cout << buff;
}
```

Or use C++ style formatting:

```
for(int j = 0; j < m.rows; j++){
    cout << precision(1) << setw(5) << m.at<float>(i,j);
}
```

If the array is very large, you may prefer to move these out of the loop:

```
cout.precision(1); 
cout.setw(5);
```

I prefer the last method - as it won't overflow if your calculation got 1210121281.9 as the result [your layout will look a bit funny].

Comment: Unfortunately the last method is really slow and not really suitable to put in a nested loop (where it gets called many many times).  Here it looks like the matrix isn't very big, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Also balance your parentheses.

Comment: Slow compared to printing thousands of floating point numbers?

Comment: Your first suggestion fixes it - thank you.  
The matrix is tiny (3X3), so I'm not worried about memory size or speed even a little bit, but why was it crashing?
Also, I can't compile the second suggestion - it can't find the precision or setw functions.
And the suggestion above from @Grimes fixes it independently.
`std::vector<std::string> args; for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) args.push_back(argv[i]);`  I'd love to know why.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my first "fix" fixes nothing - it probably just doesn't crash any longer because you are overwriting something on your own stack, rather than writing beyond the end of an allocated pointer. I would suggest that you go for a solution where you don't rely on fixed size buffer simply to print a number. Use the functions provided in C++ to print floating point numbers.

Comment: @Mats: Yes, `cout` formatting operations are very slow compared to file writes, under every standard library I've seen.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/4340396/103167

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that `cout` isn't ideal, but then you wouldn't want to print a really huge array anyways... :)

Comment: Tried to switch to answer 2

`ostream has no member named setw`?  Also now i get scientific notation on large/small numbers

Comment: You may need to `#include <iomanip>` and use `cout << fixed ` to avoid scientific notation.

Answer (score 1):

The fixed-size buffer is a warning sign to me.

As a troubleshooting step, change

```
sprintf(buff, "%5.1f ", m.at<float>(i,j));
```

to

```
int const used = sprintf(buff, "%5.1f ", m.at<float>(i,j));
assert(used < 10);
```

Besides that, using dynamic allocation there is plain ridiculous.  If a fixed-size buffer is enough, just use a local automatic array variable.  While you're at it, stack space is cheap, so head off overflows by making the buffer plenty big.

```
void dumpFloatMatrix( Mat m )
{
    char buff[400];
    for(int i = 0; i < m.cols; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < m.rows; j++){
            int const used = sprintf(buff, "%5.1f ", m.at<float>(i,j));
            assert(used * sizeof *buff < sizeof buff);
            cout << buff;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```