# Why does std::hex lead to memory corruption vector.size()?

Tags: c++, iostream, memory-corruption

I have following code:

```
vector<UINT_PTR> test = GetMemoryAddresses();

cout << "Size: " << test.size() << endl;

for (UINT_PTR a : test) {
    cout << "Memory Address: " << hex  << a << endl;
}

cout << "Size: " << test.size() << endl;
```

Which prints following results:

```
Size: 18
Memory Address: fc06a0
Memory Address: 13a70f0
Memory Address: 36c78c1
Memory Address: 3da0ea0
Memory Address: 3e21b80
Memory Address: c0a6881
Memory Address: c747690
Memory Address: c748b98
Memory Address: c74a1b8
Memory Address: c74ce10
Memory Address: c750c78
Memory Address: 1340a10f
Memory Address: 14376ea0
Memory Address: 14472649
Memory Address: 69867268
Memory Address: 6bdf9243
Memory Address: 7399a142
Memory Address: 76c54875
Size: 12
```

Removing the

> << hex

leads to the correct vector.size() of 18 again.

What is causing this memory coruption?

Have I done anything wrong?

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273330/restore-the-state-of-stdcout-after-manipulating-it) on saving and restoring a stream's state.

Comment: This is because `<iostream>` and `<iomanip>` are [completely broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52442415/in-c-am-i-paying-for-what-i-am-not-eating/52462699#52462699). You should just include `<cstdio>` and use `std::fprintf()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::hex` is "sticky".  It sets the state of the stream to hexadecimal display and that is where it will stay until you change it.  That means when you do

```
cout << "Size: " << test.size() << endl;
```

you display the size in hex and 18 decimal is 12 hex.

You need

```
cout << "Size: " << dec << test.size() << endl;
```

to switch back to decimal mode and display the size "correctly".

---

Another thing that would help you diagnosing this is to use [`std::showbase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/showbase).  It is another "sticky" manipulator and will prepend hexadecimal output with `0x`.  Using that in

```
cout << "Memory Address: " << hex << showbase  << a << endl;
```

would have made your output

```
Size: 18
Memory Address: 0xfc06a0
Memory Address: 0x13a70f0
Memory Address: 0x36c78c1
Memory Address: 0x3da0ea0
Memory Address: 0x3e21b80
Memory Address: 0xc0a6881
Memory Address: 0xc747690
Memory Address: 0xc748b98
Memory Address: 0xc74a1b8
Memory Address: 0xc74ce10
Memory Address: 0xc750c78
Memory Address: 0x1340a10f
Memory Address: 0x14376ea0
Memory Address: 0x14472649
Memory Address: 0x69867268
Memory Address: 0x6bdf9243
Memory Address: 0x7399a142
Memory Address: 0x76c54875
Size: 0x12
```

which makes it a lot more clear that the last call to `cout` is still using `hex`

Comment: Jesus christ why is C++ like that. Thanks <3

Comment: @Ojav I cannot wait for fmt to be standardized.

Comment: @Ojav Don't worry about it.  Some manipulators are not "sticky" and some are.  It takes time to learn which is which.

Comment: @Ojav it really isnt obvious by reading some otherwise wonderful [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex), though if you read the example carefully they mention: "// the output base is sticky until changed"

Comment: TIL. Confusing business with most common stream manipulators not sticking.

Comment: @user463035818 Men i even was at that site, I never felt more stupid ever

Comment: @Ojav Don't worry about it. Stream manipulators are tricky like that, and everyone makes mistakes like this once in a while.

Comment: @Ojav I've updated the answer with a useful debug tip for this.

Comment: @Ojav not your fault, if I didnt miss it they dont mention it at all in the text, maybe it should get an update

Answer (score 6):

```
std::cout << std::hex;
```

makes all numbers printed by `std::cout` print as hex. To get back to decimal again run:

```
std::cout << std::dec;
```

Ideally before using any stream format manipulators (like `std::hex`) you should save the formatting flags and restore them when you are finished. For example:

```
auto flags = std::cout.flags();
std::cout << std::hex << 10 << "\n";
std::cout.flags( flags );
```

All of the flags need to be reset like this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/flags

The fill character is also sticky: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fill and so is the precision: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/precision

The only one that  isn't is the width flag: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/width

Boost has a utility class to reset all the stream state back to the initial values: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/io/doc/ios_state.html

Comment: @Ojav it didnt change, 0x12 is 18

Comment: Thanks to you too kind sir

Comment: @StoryTeller nope, `setw` resets on the next output operation but the other flags don't